# How to migrate IconButton and Button with activeClassName attribute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have code that is not compiling in typescript

```
  <IconButton
    activeClassName="Mui-active"
    component={RouterLink}
    onClick={closeSidebar}
    to={link}
  >

  <Button
    disableRipple
    activeClassName="Mui-active"
    component={RouterLink}
    onClick={closeSidebar}
    to={link}
    startIcon={Icon && <Icon />}
  >
```

I am not quite sure how to port both of these?  At least I am guessing the theme I am copying from is on a previous version of MUI.  The IconButton and Button come from a file in node_module @mui/material directory.

I am not quite sure how to upgrade so activeClassName is working?

Here is the exact compile error ->

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
    Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "warning" | "success" | "info" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: any[]; disableRipple: true; activeClassName: string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; onClick: () => void; to: string; startIcon: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "warning" | ... 4 more ... | "secondary"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
    Property 'activeClassName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "warning" | ... 4 more ... | "secondary"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
    Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: any[]; disableRipple: true; activeClassName: string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; onClick: () => void; to: string; startIcon: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
    Property 'activeClassName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
    Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: any[]; disableRipple: true; activeClassName: string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; onClick: () => void; to: string; startIcon: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "warning" | "success" | "info" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
    Property 'activeClassName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "warning" | "success" | "info" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
101 |       <Button
  102 |         disableRipple
> 103 |         activeClassName="Mui-active"
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
104 |         component={RouterLink}
105 |         onClick={closeSidebar}
106 |         to={link}
```